# NLog and running console application as a process

Tags: f#, nlog

I got a problem with nlog while Im running my console application as hidden process. The log entries are not written.

I have 2 targets configured (console, file) in my nlog.config file which are working perfectly if i manually run my console app.

nlog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      globalThreshold="Debug"
      internalLogFile="c:\nlog.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">

    <variable name="defaultLayout" value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message}"/>
    <variable name="logFilename" value="logs/${shortdate}.Scheduler.log"/>
    <variable name="errorLogFilename" value="logs/${shortdate}.Scheduler.log"/>

    <targets async="false">
        <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" layout="${defaultLayout}"/>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logFilename}" layout="${defaultLayout}" />
        <target name="errorFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${errorLogFilename}" layout="${defaultLayout}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,console" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="errorFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

my code responsible for starting the console app process:

```
 let setupProcess (enviromentName) (parameter) = 
        let targetPath = getTargetPath enviromentName
        let executable = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, executable)
        let startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.WindowStyle <- System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        startInfo.FileName <- executable
        startInfo.Arguments <- parameter
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
        startInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
        startInfo
```

and for starting the process:

```
 [<Fact>]
    let ``Run in debug mode``() =
        createEnviroment "debugEnv"
        let setup = setupProcess "debugEnv" "debug"
        use process' = Process.Start(setup)
        process'.BeginOutputReadLine() |> ignore
        process'.OutputDataReceived.Add(fun(args) -> printf "%s\n" args.Data)
        process'.WaitForExit(10000) |> ignore
        process'.Kill()|> ignore
```

my project can be found here: https://github.com/aph5nt/cronix

Comment: Are the log entries not written to file, to console, or both? What happens if your program just does `Console.WriteLine`, without NLog involvement?

Comment: Console.WriteLine works fine, but logging into console or file don't. The same situation is when I run my lib as a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Got that fixed!

```
<variable name="logFilename" value="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"/>
```

The default dir for windows service is C:\Windows\System32, so I had to add ${basedir} to the output log path, so now it points to the location when my windows service is installed.